# Mutiple tables with one data type broken down

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have 3 tables I would be referencing to create one table - called **Output Report** last able created - and I need a bit of guidance on whether my process makes sense:

**Table 1: Lot**

| Lot_Name | Lot_ID | Lot_Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC01 | 123A | 50 |
| ABC02 | 123B | 100 |
| ABC03 | 123C | 20 |

**Table 2: Txn_History**

| Lot_ID | Txn_Type | Txn_Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123A | 1 | 5 |
| 123A | 2 | 10 |
| 123A | 3 | 5 |
| 123B | 1 | 10 |
| 123B | 2 | 5 |
| 123B | 3 | 10 |
| 123C | 1 | 5 |
| 123C | 1 | 10 |
| 123C | 2 | 5 |
| 123C | 4 | 10 |

**Table 3: Txn_info**

| Txn_Name | Txn_Type | Txn_grp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yield | 1 | Yield |
| Bubble | 2 | Scrap |
| Warping | 3 | Scrap |
| Bent | 4 | Scrap |

**Table 4: Output Report**

| Lot_Name | Lot_Qty | Yield | Bubble | Warping | Bent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC01 | 50 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
| ABC02 | 100 | 10 | 5 | 10 | 0 |
| ABC03 | 20 | 15 | 5 | 0 | 10 |

**My Query is as follows:**

```
-- Create Table Output_Report
Select l.lot_name, l.lot_qty, 
sum(case when ti.txn_type = '1' then th.txn_qty yield end) as Yield,
sum(case when ti.txn_type = '2' then th.txn_qty yield end) as Bubble,
sum(case when ti.txn_type = '3' then th.txn_qty yield end) as Warping,
sum(case when ti.txn_type = '4' then th.txn_qty yield end) as Bent
from lot l
join txn_history th on l.lot_id=th.lot_id
join txn_info ti on th.txn_type=ti.txn_type
Group by l.Lot_Name
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting the values to populate as expected. Is there something missing from my query, or am I approaching this situation incorrectly?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Adding l.lot_qty to your group by clause should do the trick, i.e
`group by l.lot_name, l.lot_qty`

Comment: Please do not forget to mark answers as accepted if the response answers your specific question. This helps other users find answers to similar questions. I noticed that you have asked 11 questions an none of them have accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case you do not need to pivot your data, you can let SSRS do that.

Change the dataset query to

```
Select l.lot_name, l.lot_qty, ti.Txn_Type, ti.Txn_Name, th.txn_qty
from lot l
join txn_history th on l.lot_id=th.lot_id
join txn_info ti on th.txn_type=ti.txn_type
```

In your report, use matrix instead of a table, drag the lot_name fields to the 'rows' placeholder, drag the txn_name to the 'columns' placeholder and the txn_qty to the 'data' placeholder. If you want the columns in the exact order, double-click the column group (under the main design window) and change the sorting to sort by txn_type instead of txn_name.

To add the lot_qty, right-click the  lot_no cell and do 'insert column, inside group - right, then in the new cell select lot_qty from the dropdown list.

This is done from memory so may not be 100%. If this does not work, post a comment and I will mock up the design so you can see how it should look.